# How to calculate sum of all numbers in a string

Tags: java

How do I calculate the sum of all the numbers in a string?  In the example below, the expected result would be `4+8+9+6+3+5`.  My attempt is below.  Also could I calculate the sum of only those numbers which are divisible by 2?

```
int sum=0;
String s = "jklmn489pjro635ops";
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
    char temp = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(temp)) {
        int b = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp));
        sum=sum+b;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Please help to calculate the sum...

Comment: should the sum be 4+8+9+6+3+5 or 489+635?

Comment: @BackSlash num is a string that accumulates digits so it looks fine to use `num + a.charAt(i)`.

Comment: do you want to have sum of all numbers or all digits? ie what outcome you expect from string _12_3.5_ -? 11? 9? 20? 15.5?

Comment: Generally this code look fine to me. Except that you missed the case that `num` is not empty **after** you finished loop. You need to check  it for emptiness after the loop and add it to `sum` if it's not empty.

Comment: sum of 4+8+9+6+3+5 please do modification and must rply

Comment: @user3337429 So add up each single-digit ?

Comment: If i want to calculate sum of only those number which are divisible by 2 than what can i do..

Answer (score 6):

Parsing chars back to `String` and then to `Integer` is too expensive, since you already have a char. You should try doing this:

```
 String a = "jklmn489pjro635ops";
 int sum = 0;
 int evenSum = 0;
 for (char c : a.replaceAll("\\D", "").toCharArray()) {
     int digit = c - '0';
     sum += digit;
     if (digit % 2 == 0) {
         evenSum += digit;
     }
 }
 System.out.println(sum);
 System.out.println(evenSum);
```

Comment: Cool answer, but what about the *even* number requirement.

Comment: Updated with the even requirement

Answer (score 4):

This could be a simple and efficient way:

```
static int sumFromString(String s){
       int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++){
            if( Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) ){
                sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Another way was to convert char to String and then to int, which is not so efficient:

```
sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i) + "");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the simplest and easiest way

```
static int sumOfString(String str){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){              
            if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
                    sum+=str.charAt(i)-'0';
                }
        }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this..

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "jklmn489pjro635ops";

    int length = a.length();

    char c;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        c  = a.charAt(i);
        if(StringUtils.isNumeric(String.valueOf(c))) {
            count = count + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));

        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-1;){
  try{
    sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, ++i));
  }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full mainline example you can run.  This should answer your question and all the follow on questions in the comments.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class StringSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([2468])"); // Who do we appreciate!
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(args[0]);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Some example executions:

```
$ javac StringSum.java && java StringSum jklmn489pjro635ops
18
$ javac StringSum.java && java StringSum a1b2c3d4
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "jklmn489pjro635ops";

int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    if(Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(a.charAt(i) + "");
    } 
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the String");

    String input = sc.next();

    int sum = 0;

    char[] c = input.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0;i<=c.length-1;i++)
    {
      if(Character.isDigit(c[i]))
      {
          Character c1 = c[i];
          String s1 = c1.toString();
          int i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

          sum = sum+i1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int sumFromString(String str){
    int sum=0;
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()){
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)){
            sum+=(ch-'0');
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

my 5 cents - fastest variant

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "abc12xx3";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    int sum = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }
    return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int banana = 0;
String meow = "74387493";

for (int i = 0; i < meow.length(); i++) 
{
    String cows = ""+meow.charAt(i);
    int b =  Integer.parseInt(cows);
    banana = banana + b;
}

System.out.println(banana);
```

The above code will add all the numbers in a string (sorry for the silly names).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using regex, use /[a-zA-Z]/ to find the alpha string and replace with '', for demo show the program I have completed with php.

```
<?php
$str = 'jklmn489pjro635ops';
$res = preg_replace('/[a-zA-z]/', '', $str);
$sum = 0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($res);$i++){
    $sum += $res[$i];
}
echo $sum;//35
?>
```