# Summing the digits of a string using charAt

Tags: java

This is my function which should add and return the sum of the digits in a string.

```
public static int Sum(int a) {

    String row = String.valueOf(a);
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (counter<row.length()){
        int b = row.charAt(counter);
        sum = sum + b;
        counter++;      
    }

    return sum; 
}
```

I'm not sure why this does not add all the digits of the integer. Output is giving me completely wonky answers. Help would be appreciated, cheers.

Input: 8576 
Output: 218
Expected output: 8+5+7+6 = 26

Fixed:

```
public static int Sum(int a) {

    String row = String.valueOf(a);
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (counter<row.length()){
        String b = String.valueOf(row.charAt(counter));
        int c = Integer.parseInt(b);
        sum = sum + c;
        counter++;

        }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: When asking for help with these sorts of things, always show sample input, the expected sample output, and the output you're currently getting that you don't understand. [More here.](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: simply because `'0' != 0`

Comment: Input: 8756, 1, 58, 2, 0 Output: 218, 49, 109, 50, 48

Comment: Update your question instead of putting out more comments. And then: understand that you cant simply add **char** and **int** values here. The char `0` has not the same numerical value as the int 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum digits of an integer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096670/how-to-sum-digits-of-an-integer-in-java)

Comment: [Could look at this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937091/how-to-calculate-sum-of-all-numbers-in-a-string) based on the current title :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int b = Row.charAt(i);` is the problem. the integer gets the ascii value of the character.
working code is :

```
public static int Sum(int a) {
        int sum = 0;
        int rest = 1;
        while(rest!=0){
            rest = a % 10;
            a = a / 10;
            sum = sum + rest;           
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

rest is always the last digit and since int is always a non-decimal dumber and rounds automatically you can can use  `a = a / 10;` to "delete" the last digit

Comment: There is a problem with your answer, there is a huge difference between the beginning telling where is the problem and the code using a totaly different solution. Just adding `b -=  '0'; //48` would have been enought. Add some spaces to make it more obvious ;)

Comment: @AxelH Don't need the code, studying for an exam :) This method is also helpful for other questions so learning this way will help me a lot for my exam!

Comment: @Emolk Then you should try to understand how to convert `'0'` into is numerical value...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `b` is the Unicode value for the digit,¹ not the digit value. The Unicode value of the digit 1, for instance, is 49.

To sum up the *digit* values, you'll need to handle that. You could do that by using the [method Tariq mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40611158/157247), converting the character to a string and parsing it as an `int`, or using math based on the Unicode value I mentioned above.

---

¹ More pedantically, the value of the UTF-16 serialization of the digit if the character can be represented with a single code unit in UTF-16 (which the digits can). In the case of the digits (and all the 127 ASCII values), that's the same as the Unicode code point for the digit.

Comment: Or using the original `int` received.

Comment: @AxelH: Indeed, there's a mathematics way to get this answer without using strings.

Comment: Just an alternative, your answer is still the best concerning is current code.

Answer (score 2):

like above stated `int b` is getting ascii value of character,

Change

```
int b = Row.charAt(i);
```

To

```
char c = Row.charAt(i);
int b= Character.getNumericValue(c);
```

Comment: Oooh, I'd forgotten about `Character.getNumericValue`!

Comment: I didn't knew this one ! Really nice to convert non-latin digit representation.

Comment: Yeah java always has some options..Thnkx

Answer (score 0):

You are actually adding the Unicode value of the char not the numeric value. To do this take a look this method [Character#getNumericValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) 
 from JDK Character class. You can change the code as following ::

```
public static int sum(int a) {
    String Row = String.valueOf(a);
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (counter < Row.length()) {
        int b = Character.getNumericValue(Row.charAt(counter));
        sum = sum + b;
        counter++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

also you can do this by manually. Instead of this `int b = Character.getNumericValue(Row.charAt(counter));` line you can do `int b = Row.charAt(counter) - '0';` It is like if you have char `1` and Unicode value of this is 49 and the Unicode value of `0` is 48. When you are subtracting  with the `1` char value with the `0` then you will get the actual numeric value of the char `1`.