# Find Sum From String of Numbers

Tags: java

```
String code = "12345";
int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<=4; i++){
            sum = sum + code.charAt(i);
               
        }
return sum;
```

I have tried this but I get 255 as the sum.

Comment: You need to parse the char-values to ints before summing it up

Comment: Digit characters are numbered starting at `48`.  So `49+50+51+52+53=255`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate sum of all numbers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937091/how-to-calculate-sum-of-all-numbers-in-a-string)

Comment: Change `sum = sum + code.charAt(i);` to `sum = sum + code.charAt(i)-'0';` and try it. That will convert the ASCII digit to its representative numeric value.  But the code does not discriminate against other, non-digit characters so it isn't fool proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it.

```
String string =
        "This12is  mix of 3 characters 45spaces and numbers 67";
```

- initialize sum to `0`;
- loop thru all the characters
- Check that the character is a digit
- if so, subtract `'0'` and sum the result.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        sum = sum + c - '0';
    }
}
```

Prints

```
28
```

**About subtracting `'0'`**

ASCII and Unicode characters are binary values that are encoded for display on some output device.  This includes digits.  However, digits are not in proper format for numeric computations so they need to be converted to their numeric binary format. The easiest way is to subtract decimal 48 (which is the encoded representation for the digit 0) from each digit prior to summing them.  For larger numbers like "29929" `Integer.parseInt()` can be used.  Internally it does similar processing of the individual digits as previously described.

Answer (score 1):

Strings can't be used for arithmetic operation, so parse the string to integer first.

```
String code = "12345";
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++){
    sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(code.charAt(i)));
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing from the attached codeblock is parsing the strings as integers, and using the length of the string instead of a hard coded number.

```
String code = "12345";
int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) { 
            char temp = code.charAt(i);
            sum += Integer.parseInt(temp);
            } 
        return sum;
```

```
// Java program to calculate sum of all numbers present 
// in a string containing alphanumeric characters 
class GFG { 
  
    // Function to calculate sum of all numbers present 
    // in a string containing alphanumeric characters 
    static int findSum(String str) 
    { 
        // A temporary string 
        String temp = "0"; 
  
        // holds sum of all numbers present in the string 
        int sum = 0; 
  
        // read each character in input string 
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { 
            char ch = str.charAt(i); 
  
            // if current character is a digit 
            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) 
                temp += ch; 
  
            // if current character is an alphabet 
            else { 
                // increment sum by number found earlier 
                // (if any) 
                sum += Integer.parseInt(temp); 
  
                // reset temporary string to empty 
                temp = "0"; 
            } 
        } 
  
        // atoi(temp.c_str()) takes care of trailing 
        // numbers 
        return sum + Integer.parseInt(temp); 
    } 
  
    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
  
        // input alphanumeric string 
        String str = "12abc20yz68"; 
  
        // Function call 
        System.out.println(findSum(str)); 
    } 
} 
  
// This code is contributed by AnkitRai01
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calculate-sum-of-all-numbers-present-in-a-string/)

Comment: While I appreciate that you've provided proper attribution, answers which do not add anything beyond what is already on the web aren't really great answers.  This would be better as a comment with a link to the source.  I realize you don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but you'll get there.  In the meantime, focus on answering good-quality questions.  It will help you write better quality answers, and it serves the site better, since it prioritizes people who have put more effort into their questions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to StackOverflow and was trying to edit it a real answer above that codeblock. 

I trimmed it down to the relevant pieces for the OP, but still wanted to leave the original page for context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```
public static void main(String []args){
        String code = "12345";
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++){
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(code.charAt(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```